# How to return a series of number from a recursive function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion, dynamic-programming, return-type

I use dynamic programming for finding the shortest path between two matrices. I printed all the step of the shortest path, but I would also like to save all of them so I can print them as a 2D figure. I wrote the code like below but it doesn't work. I searched on the internet and it seems like it need to be pass by an object as the argument? Does anyone know how to get the path matrix from the returning value? Thanks in advance!

```
ttt=find_path(7,7)

function pathMat = find_path(a,b)
pathMat=[];
if (a==0 || b==0)
    return;
end

filename = sprintf('/Users/name/Desktop/song1.wav');
[x, Fs]=audioread(filename);
s=x;
filename = sprintf('/Users/name/Desktop/song2.wav');
[x, Fs]=audioread(filename);
t=x;

% dynamic time warping
w=-Inf;
ns=size(s,2);
nt=size(t,2);

%% initialization
D=zeros(ns+2,nt+2)-Inf; % cache matrix
D(1,1)=0;
D(2,2)=0;

% similarity matrix (cosing similarity)
oost = zeros(ns+1,nt+1)-Inf;
for i=1:ns
for j=1:nt
        oost(i+1,j+1) = 
(dot(s(:,i),t(:,j))/(norm(s(:,i),2)*norm(t(:,j),2))); % = cos(theta)
    end
end

%% begin dynamic programming
%find the maximal similarity between two matrix 

for i=1:ns
    for j=1:nt
        D(i+2,j+2)=oost(i+1,j+1)+max([D(i,j+1)+oost(i,j+1), D(i+1,j)+oost(i+1,j), D(i+1,j+1)]);
    end
end
d=max(D(:,nt+2));
d_len=nt+2;

while(max(D(:,d_len))==-Inf)
    d_len=d_len-1;
    d=max(D(:,d_len));
end


fprintf('(%d, %d)', a, b);
pathMat = [pathMat];

if (max([D(a,b+1)+oost(a,b+1), D(a+1,b)+oost(a+1,b), D(a+1,b+1)])==D(a,b+1)+oost(a,b+1))
    fprintf('(%d, %d)', a-1, b);
    pathMat=[pathMat;find_path(a-1,b)];
    find_path(a-2,b-1);
elseif (max([D(a,b+1)+oost(a,b+1), D(a+1,b)+oost(a+1,b), D(a+1,b+1)])==D(a+1,b)+oost(a+1,b))
    fprintf('(%d, %d)', a, b-1);
    pathMat=[pathMat;find_path(a,b-1)];
    find_path(a-1,b-2);
elseif (max([D(a,b+1)+oost(a,b+1), D(a+1,b)+oost(a+1,b), D(a+1,b+1)])==D(a+1,b+1))
    find_path(a-1,b-1);

end
end
```

Comment: It is preferred to post only that much code as is needed to understand the problem, to avoid distraction and clutter. I have posted a solution assuming a simpler problem as an example, do check if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two approaches** you can use, to retain values between function calls or store all results in a "global" variable.

Due to the clutter and length of your code (not everything is relevant to the question), I will **take the example of a factorial program** to describe the approach.

Let there be a function that not only computes the factorial of the given number **recursively**, but also all the intermediate results of numbers lesser than itself. I believe this is a close model of what you require. An example of what the function should do:

```
>> [fact, list] = factorial(5)
>>     fact = 120
>>     list = [1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

---

### Approach 1: Use `persistent` variables

[Persistent variables](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) are the equivalent of static function variables (like in C) in MATLAB.

Persistent variables by default are assigned to `[]` on first use. Also, the value is retained across function calls as expected. A sample code using this approach to define our factorial program:

```
function [fact, list] = factorial(n)
    if n <= 1
        fact = 1;
    else
        fact = n * factorial(n-1);
    end

    persistent res;
    res = [res, fact];
    list = res;
end
```

This can be used as follows:

```
>> [f, list] = factorial(4)

f =
    24

list =
     1     2     6    24

>> clear factorial
>> [f, list] = factorial(3)

f =
     6

list =
     1     2     6
```

---

### Approach 2: Sharing variables in nested functions

MATLAB supports [nested function definitions](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html), where the inner functions can **share variables** from the outer one, and modify them without explicitly being passing as arguments. A sample code using this approach:

```
function [fact, list] = factorial(n)
    list = [];
    fact = factorial_core(n);

    function fact = factorial_core(n)
        if n <= 1
            fact = 1;
        else
            fact = n * factorial_core(n-1);
        end
        list = [list, fact];
    end
end
```

This is used the same way as before, except that `clear factorial` (that clears the persistent variables) between function calls is not required.

---

I would recommend you to try out whichever suits your case best. Also, it appears that you are loading the `wav` files each time of the recursion, which is unnecessary and inefficient. These two approaches can be used to avoid that, apart from solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks you! I use the first approach and solve this problem!